# iframes wont work in wordpress with html or plugin

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe

I cant figure out why I'm not able to embed an external website into a wordpress page. I tried html and several plug ins nothing works. Is there something blocking me from using iframes in wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

iframes are not supported in Wordpress by default. The following [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/iframe/) let's you insert iframes in Wordpress

Answer (score 0):

you can insert an iframe into a custom page template and it will work. it can look very messy however, especially with a responsive theme.